# How to use QSignalMapper to map integers to numerals?

Tags: qt, qsignalmapper

I have problems with a simple application in Qt. The app looks like a simple calculator wtih buttons (digits from 0 to 9).

Once a button is clicked application shall display on the application’s output the corresponding number as a digit and as a numeral (a word).

I need to use `QSignalMapper`. How can I solve this?

My code so far:

```
QLayout* Widget::createButtons()
{
    QGridLayout     *lt = new QGridLayout(this);
    QSignalMapper   *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);

    connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(keyPressed(int)));

    QString txtButtons[10] = {"zero", "one", "two", 
                              "three", "four", "five",
                              "six", "seven", "eight", 
                              "nine"};

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {

        buttons[i] = new QPushButton(txtButtons[i], this);
        signalMapper->setMapping(buttons[i], i);
        connect(buttons[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        lt->addWidget(buttons[i], i/3, i%3);
    }

    return lt;
}

void Widget::keyPressed(int buttonID)
{
    qDebug() << QString::number(buttonID) + " was clicked";
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html#details)?

Comment: Yes, I have wrote this line of code for example:
    `button9 = new QPushButton(tr("9"), this);
    connect(button9, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), m, SLOT(map()));
    m->setMapping(button0, 9);`

Comment: Please provide your code in the post and not in the comment section. The more useful information your provide (especially code snippets), the better and faster the answer will come.

Comment: Is that a class assignment? In Qt 5 you don't need to use the signal mapper anymore :) Even in Qt 4 you don't have to, you can assign each button a dynamic property specifying the number/word.

Comment: ok, my code has a little changed

Comment: Your code works fine, what is your question?

Comment: Once a button is clicked application shall display on the application’s output the corresponding number as a digit and as a word.

For example: 0, zero

My code only display: 0

Comment: I see, there is no existing qt way to translate number into word, the answer below has one of the possible solutions. Your SignalMapper code works.

Comment: @Kuba: Please elaborate: In which way does Qt5 make QSignalMapper obsolete? How can one add a dynamic property in Qt4?

Comment: @Silicomancer See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22641306/1329652) for three ways of mapping one of a multitude of objects to a value. The use of `QSignalMapper` is not necessary in Qt 5, and is optional in Qt 4.

Below is an example of the use of `QSignalMapper` in Qt4/5. There are three points to keep in mind to use `QSignalMapper`:

1. Use the `setMapping` method to add a mapping between a sender `QObject` instance, and a value (integer, string, etc.).
2. Connect the sender's signal to the `map` slot in the mapper.
3. Connect the mapper's `mapped(ValueType)` signal to the consumer of the mapping. `ValueType` is the type you're mapping to - here, it'd be `QString`.

[image: screenshot of the example]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/button-grid-37492290
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif
const QString numerals[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
                            "eight", "nine", "ten"};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QGridLayout layout{&w};
   QLabel label;
   QSignalMapper mapper;
   QPushButton buttons[10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      auto n = qMax(7-(3*(i/3))+i%3, 0); // numpad layout
      auto & button = buttons[i];
      button.setText(QString::number(n));
      mapper.setMapping(&button, QString("%1 - %2").arg(n).arg(numerals[n]));
      mapper.connect(&button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SLOT(map()));
      layout.addWidget(&button, 1+i/3, i%3, 1, n > 0 ? 1 : 3);
   }
   layout.addWidget(&label, 0, 0, 1, 3);
   label.connect(&mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), SLOT(setText(QString)));
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QString::number(buttonID)` only displays text as a number, but it does not print that number in a word. For printting in a word you could recycle your `QString txtButtons[]`:

```
QString txtButtons[10] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
```

(It should be txtButtons[9], 0 counts too! But you could use `QStringList` better http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html)

Take that words for displaying after the number:

```
void Widget::keyPressed(int buttonID)
{
    qDebug() << QString::number(buttonID) + ", " + **txtButtons[buttonID]** + " was clicked";
}
```

Comment: So, shall I declare `QString txtButtons[]` as class member.

Comment: I can't initialize `QString` array :(

Comment: You better use QStringList:

Comment: Yes, declare this QStringList in your .h file (but only declare, don't initialize), and initialize it as follows (replace QString array by this): 

QStringList txtButtons << "zero" << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" << "five" << "six" << "seven" << "eight" << "nine";

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works.I took the words for displaying like this:

`void Widget::keyPressed(int buttonID)
    {
        qDebug() << "Button clicked: "  << buttons[buttonID]->text().trimmed()
                 << " with ID "         << buttonID;
    }`

How can I declare this QStringList as a pointer like : `QStringList      *txtButtons;`

Comment: This topic may help you about "QStringList as a pointer": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178815/using-the-operator-with-a-qstringlist-pointer